# Running .bat file using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a batch file which runs when i directly double click on it. But it is not running when i run it thorough excel vba. Below is the code which i have used.

```
Dim RetVal
    RetVal = Shell("C:\Script.bat", 1)
End Sub
```

I have the script in text file and created a batch file and entered the code as `ftp -i -s:script.txt`. It runs fine when i clicked on the batch file.

script entered in text file is,

```
open aa123.aa1.aaa.com
user
pwd
ascii
lcd C:\Users\sakthi\Desktop
cd data/folder
get filename.zip
bye
```

1. When i run the bat file, by default CMD is checking for the related text file from My Documents but i have the associated text file in the same folder. How to change it to an specific folder?
2. It takes only 20 seconds to complete the run when i clicked directly on the batch file. But it takes more than a minute when i run the batch file using macro and gets timeout error in CMD screen. How to resolve it?

Comment: Include either the relevant code of the batch file and your VBA code or better build an [mcve] so the issue can be reproduced. From what you posted we cannot see why your code does not work as expected.

Comment: Hello, I have used the below code in text document

open aaa.bbb.ccc.com (Next Row)
user (Next Row)
pass (Next Row)
ascii (Next Row)
lcd C:\Users\sakthi\Desktop (Next Row)
cd inflow/docs (Next Row)
get document.zip (Next Row)
bye (Next Row)

I have entered the text in separate rows but not reflecting in this comment box. so i have added a note where i have line break as (Next Row)

Comment: Please add everything into your original question ([edit]) and format it as code block (Ctrl + K), code in comments is not readable. Include a full [mcve] and explain it as detailed as possible. A one line comment will probably not be enough information to understand what exactly you did.

Comment: I have added the required details in the question. Could someone help me on this?